# Plot horizontal bar order by DESC value of column

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, bar-chart, visualization

I have this dataframe

[image]

I try to show graph by this code

```py
sns.barplot(data=africa_all_percent,y="country", x="suicide_percent_for_all_pop",palette='plasma',orient="h")
```

it's give me this results

[image]

I try to order by desc with this code

```py
orderX = africa_all_percent['suicide_percent_for_all_pop'].sort_values(ascending=False)

sns.barplot(data=africa_all_percent,y="country", x="suicide_percent_for_all_pop",palette='plasma',orient="h",order = orderX)
```

[image]

look like it's not work, I tried some solutions but it's still not work.

solution or code guiding for order by desc in this graph.

Comment: You need the index of `orderX` here: `sns.barplot(...., order = orderX.index)`

Comment: Thank you , i tried but it's show nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply sort your dataframe before plotting:

```
africa_all_percent = africa_all_percent.sort_values('suicide_percent_for_all_pop', ascending=False)
```

Output:

[image]